# Call Javascript script before page_load method in Master page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to call a javascript script before the page_load method in the MasterPage.cs.

I need to do this because I want to recover a javascript variable that will be used in the page_Load method.

Someone know how to do?

Thank you,

Quentin

Answer (score 1):

In start of Page_Load or in Page_Init method you can call javascript like:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "TestKey", "YourJavascriptMethod();", true);
```

Comment: put an alert in your javascript method and see if it gets called.